# Logitech G5 mouse loses motion settings when certain programs are opened

Tags: windows-7, drivers, logitech-mouse

This has driven me beyond nuts over the past year and I've had no luck hunting down a solution.

Basically, I use a Logitech G5 mouse because I like being able to program the various buttons to things like Back and moving windows between monitors.

The problem I have is whenever I open up certain programs, the pointer speed settings change to a much faster level and even interfere with button settings. I can get the settings back by opening Setpoint and clicking OK, but it's a real pain.

Currently, the offending program is Perforce on 64-bit Windows 7. In the past, I ran into the problem with MySQL Workbench on 32-bit Windows XP. So two different computers, OSs and programs. Same issue. It's not a long list of programs, but in both cases, it's a program that I use a lot. If I change the mouse settings after opening the program, it messes up the settings once Setpoint is reinitialized. So I have just needed to suck up the faster mouse speed setting while Perforce is open.

I have the latest version of SetPoint and mouse driver, at least the last time I checked a few months ago. I've been dealing with this since 2011.

Any ideas?

FYI - I'm using SetPoint 6.32.7, driver version 5.33.14.

Answer (score 0):

Played around with it some more and I think I found a solution. At least it seems to work.

In Setpoint's Game Settings tab, I set Speed and Acceleration to SetPoint Implemention and unchecked Retain OS Settings. I also unchecked Game Detection "Enabled".

In the Advanced Settinsg, I unchecked "Enable application specific button settings".

This seems to force Setpoint to ignore OS settings counter to it's own and avoid making changes upon the opening of any new applications. Exactly what I was looking for.

Hope this helps others.